# ¿Como validar campos de archivos de texto (fopen) en php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Necesito saber como se pueden validar campos de archivos de texto... Éste es mi codigo:

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload('InputTXT')) {
        $fileData = $this->upload->data();
        $nombrefitxer = $fileData['file_name'];
        $csvFile =  "./assets/upload/txt/" . $nombrefitxer;

        $f = fopen($csvFile, "r");
        while (!feof($f)) 
        {
          $content = fgets($f);
          $array = explode(",",$content);
          //estructura: cuil,apellido,nombre,dni,id_sexo,id_genero,
          //fecha_nacimiento,id_nacionalidad,linea_cel,linea_fijo,
          //linea_alternativa,id_pais,id_provincia,id_localidad,cp,
          //dir_calle,dir_num,dir_piso,dir_dpto,dir_calle_1,dir_calle_2,email,activo
          list($cuil,$apellido,$nombre,$dni,$id_sexo,$id_genero,$fecha_nacimiento,$id_nacionalidad,$linea_cel,$linea_fijo,$linea_alternativa,$id_pais,$id_provincia,$id_localidad,$cp,$dir_calle,$dir_num,$dir_piso,$dir_dpto,$dir_calle_1,$dir_calle_2,$email,$activo) = $array;
          var_dump($array);
          //aca se pondrian los inserts:
        
        }
        fclose($f);
    }else{
      echo $this->upload->display_errors(); 
    }
```

Yo lo que deseo lograr, es que antes de poner los inserts o ingresar los datos a la base de datos, validar si el campo email es de tipo email...

Mi proyecto tiene dos formas de ingresar datos a la base de datos, una es masiva por .txt y otra individualmente por un formulario. En el formulario tengo las validaciones y son estas:

```
$("#formulario-registro").validate({
        rules: {
            cuil:{required:true,number:true,rangelength:[6,11],},
            apellido:{required:true,rangelength:[2,30],noSpace:true},
            nombre:{required:true,rangelength:[2,30],noSpace:true},
            dni:{required:true,number:true,rangelength:[7,8]},
            fechaNacimiento:{required:true},
            celular:{number:true,rangelength:[10,14]},
            telefonofijo:{number:true,rangelength:[10,14]},
            lineadecontacto:{number:true,rangelength:[10,14]},
            calle:{rangelength:[2,20],noSpace:true},
            numero:{number:true,rangelength:[1,3]},
            piso:{number:true,rangelength:[1,3]},
            departamento:{rangelength:[2,20],noSpace:true},
            calle1:{rangelength:[2,20],noSpace:true},
            calle2:{rangelength:[2,20],noSpace:true},
            cp:{number:true,rangelength:[3,5]},
            correoelectronico:{laxEmail:true}
        },
        errorClass: "mensajeerrorfondoazul",
        errorElement: "span",
    });
```

Yo deseo lograr lo mismo, pero para la carga masiva de datos con archivos de texto.

El archivo .txt tiene la siguiente Estructura:
cuil,apellido,nombre,dni,id_sexo,id_genero,fecha_nacimiento,id_nacionalidad,linea_cel,linea_fijo,linea_alternativa,id_pais,id_provincia,id_localidad,cp,dir_calle,dir_num,dir_piso,dir_dpto,dir_calle_1,dir_calle_2,email,activo

Ejemplo
23284147669,Weth,gise,28414766,1,,23051982,,,,2929480435,,,,6417,Irigoyen,1150,,,,,weth@gmail.com,1

Una solucion que se me ocurrio pero no me convece es recorrer y con un switch case poner las condiciones:

```
$content = fgets($f);
$array = explode(",",$content);
    foreach ($array as $clave=>$valor)
              {
                //echo "El valor de $clave es: $valor";
                switch ($clave) {
                  case 0:
                      echo "i es igual a 0";
                      break;
                  case 1:
                      echo "i es igual a 1";
                      break;
                  case 2:
                      echo "i es igual a 2";
                      break;
                  case 2:
                      echo "i es igual a 2";
                      break;
                }
              }
```

Comment: Tienes dos opciones: validarlo sobre la marcha (Solo insertar los que contengan un correo valido y mostrar la cantidad de no validos)  o validarlo primero (Recorrer todas las filas)  y si todo va bien  insertar.   ¿Cuál de las dos prefieres ?

Comment: @WilfredoAleman solo insertar las filas con validaciones correctas.

Comment: @WilfredoAleman Puede ser la primer opcion..

Comment: podes usar [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php) para leer los headers y las lineas directo a un array, luego es validar por row y por key usando [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.validate.php) mapeado a los types

Comment: @aloMalbarez fgetcsv me daba error, por eso no implemente esa función.

Comment: Cuál es la duda entonces? Validar el formato de una cadena que tiene que corresponderse con un email?

Comment: @Jakala Mi duda es como hago las validaciones que hice con Jquery (puse el ejemplo en el post) pero ahora con la carga de un .txt. Necesito validar la informacion que esta dentro del .txt

Comment: @Jakala ahi edite el post, pero no me convece esa posible solucion.

Comment: @Jakala donde pondria una variable boolean, antes del foreach la inicializo en false;

Comment: y donde estan los echo, hago los condicionales.

Comment: recién veo el tag codeigniter, que versión es? codeigniter viene con una [librería de validación para el helper de forms](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html), CI4 [varía un poco](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero haber entendido bien tu pregunta. Creo que habría que revisar más cosas  al recibir el archivo TXT (no sólo si el e-mail es válido), pero como respuesta a tu pregunta, a ver si te sirve lo siguiente:

```
/*
* Method: email_rfc
*  Validate email, RFC compliant version
*
*  Originally by Cal Henderson, modified to fit Kohana syntax standards:
*  - http://www.iamcal.com/publish/articles/php/parsing_email/
*  - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/
*
* Parameters:
*  email - email address
*
* Returns:
*  TRUE if email is valid, FALSE if not.
*/
function validateEmail($email){
    $qtext = '[^\\x0d\\x22\\x5c\\x80-\\xff]';
    $dtext = '[^\\x0d\\x5b-\\x5d\\x80-\\xff]';
    $atom  = '[^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]+';
    $pair  = '\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f]';

    $domain_literal = "\\x5b($dtext|$pair)*\\x5d";
    $quoted_string  = "\\x22($qtext|$pair)*\\x22";
    $sub_domain     = "($atom|$domain_literal)";
    $word           = "($atom|$quoted_string)";
    $domain         = "$sub_domain(\\x2e$sub_domain)*";
    $local_part     = "$word(\\x2e$word)*";
    $addr_spec      = "$local_part\\x40$domain";

    return (bool) preg_match('/^'.$addr_spec.'$/', $email);
}


if ($this->upload->do_upload('InputTXT')) {
    $fileData = $this->upload->data();
    $nombrefitxer = $fileData['file_name'];
    $csvFile =  "./assets/upload/txt/" . $nombrefitxer;
    $idsemailinvalido = array();

    $f = fopen($csvFile, "r");
    while (!feof($f)) 
    {
    $content = fgets($f);
    $array = explode(",",$content);
    //estructura: cuil,apellido,nombre,dni,id_sexo,id_genero,
    //fecha_nacimiento,id_nacionalidad,linea_cel,linea_fijo,
    //linea_alternativa,id_pais,id_provincia,id_localidad,cp,
    //dir_calle,dir_num,dir_piso,dir_dpto,dir_calle_1,dir_calle_2,email,activo
    list($cuil,$apellido,$nombre,$dni,$id_sexo,$id_genero,$fecha_nacimiento,$id_nacionalidad,$linea_cel,$linea_fijo,$linea_alternativa,$id_pais,$id_provincia,$id_localidad,$cp,$dir_calle,$dir_num,$dir_piso,$dir_dpto,$dir_calle_1,$dir_calle_2,$email,$activo) = $array;
    //var_dump($array);
    if (validateEmail($email)) {
        //aca se pondrian los inserts:
    } else {
        //////// Gestión de elementos con e-mail no válido. Por ejemplo...
        $idsemailinvalido[] = $cuil;
    }
    }
    
    }
    fclose($f);


    //////////////// Aviso de filas no insertadas. Es sólo un ejemplo
    if (count($idsemailinvalido)>0) {
        echo "Ha habido ".count($idsemailinvalido)." elementos no insertados: ".implode(",",$idsemailinvalido);
    }
}else{
    echo $this->upload->display_errors(); 
}
```

Comment: Hola! Si, en un principio si! En total son 22 campos los que tengo que validar! Uno de ellos era email, pero tambien por ejemplo el campo Nombre, tengo que validar que no tenga mas de 20 caracteres, que no sea null, y que no contenga numeros.

Comment: Así con los 22 atributos... De la forma que me lo planteas vos seria lo mas corto? por que me va a quedar medio extenso el codigo... no ?

Comment: Los campos que tengo que validar son los puse en éste post, de ejemplo, como lo hago con Jquery.

Comment: Lo que haces con Jquery puede estar bien, pero te vale para la introducción de datos individual desde el formulario. Aún así, en estos casos también haría una validación en la parte del servidor y no sólo en navegador. Pero lo que pides es una validación para la carga masiva (con el TXT), por lo que has de hacerlo desde el servidor. Y no hay códigos demasiado extensos. Los hay buenos o malos. Eficientes o ineficientes. Pero ¿Es la longitud del código un parámetro para valorarlo?

Comment: Sobre el tema de validar todos los campos... Depende de si quieres que la aplicación sea robusta o no, Gisela. Y después... para minimizar código, especialmente repetitivo y para no tener que escribir todo tú, siempre puedes utilizar librerías ya hechas. El tema es buscar agluna que te convenza, pero eso es cosa tuya ya. Imagínate, por ejemplo y sin ir más legos, https://github.com/rakit/validation que es una librería que te ayudará para todos los casos que tienes en este ejemplo: requerido, numérico, rango (between), etc. Mi respuesta inicial se refería solo a tu pregunta sobre email.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: mirate tambien php. En la documentacion, tienes la instruccion `filter_var`. que te permite añadir filtro a cada dato. Asi puedes saber si es un email: if `filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` por ej, te indicara un true si corresponde a un email valido

Comment: Todavía me acabo de dar cuenta ahora de que has etiquetado la pregunta con codeigniter, así que te añado más: codeigniter tiene herramientas también de validación sin tener que recurrir a librerías externas.